# Log STDOUT and STDERR with SLF4J, but run as a daemon

Tags: java, stdout, slf4j, stderr

I found this earlier today and it solved an issue I had very nicely:

[Redirect System.out and System.err to slf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187461/redirect-system-out-and-system-err-to-slf4j)

However, it resulted in another issue: to make this work, I couldn't close stdout and stderr when running my code otherwise I wouldn't get the log messages.  This causes an issue when starting the daemon as it locks up the terminal.  Hitting Ctrl+C works, but it's not elegent.

So, does anyone know a way where I can capture messages sent to STDOUT or STDERR and still be disconnected from the terminal?

Comment: would you add your code or what you currently have, so we can better help you, please ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't show you my code in it's current form.  The relevant code is nothing more than instantiating the logger and using it (E.g. logger.info(...)) plus what is described in that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.K.  I figured it out.  I didn't notice it before, but the code I referenced kept the old streams for System.out and System.err in case the user wanted to revert back to printing to either.  Removing that code resolved my issue.

EDIT: Also, had to redirect stdout/stderr to /dev/null with the following at the end of the java command to launch the process:

```
2>/dev/null 1>&2 &
```

This appears to be working fine.  Hopefully this is useful to someone else in the future.