# How to selectively redirect system.out to files according to the packages

Tags: java, redirect, logging

My java program uses lib A. 
my java program uses System.out.print(). And lib A also use System.out.print().
But I only want the console show the output of system.out.print() from my program. Don't want the console show the log from lib A.
how to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Bad libs :) You should all use a proper logging framework.

Comment: This might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187461/redirect-system-out-and-system-err-to-slf4j You can redirect System.out/err to slf4j and have it route the messages based on package.

Comment: but I still want to see the output of system.out from my program.

Answer (score 1):

If performance and maintainability is not an issue you can filter the existing System.out stream by creating a print stream that checks the caller before doing anything.  Here is some example code to get you going but you'll have to override every method to check the caller:

```
 public class PackagePrintStream extends PrintStream {

    public PackagePrintStream(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush, String encoding) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        super(out, autoFlush, encoding);
    }

    @Override
    public void println(Object x) {
        /**
         * You have to override all of the PrintStream methods
         * not just println.
         */
        if (allow()) {
            super.println(x); 
        }
    }

    private boolean allow() {
        String cn = inferCaller().getClassName();
        return !cn.startsWith("lib.A"); //@todo use the right package name.
    }

    private boolean isPrintImplFrame(String cname) {
        return PackagePrintStream.class.getName().equals(cname);
    }

    private StackTraceElement inferCaller() {
        StackTraceElement stack[] = (new Throwable()).getStackTrace();
        int ix = 0;
        while (ix < stack.length) {
            StackTraceElement frame = stack[ix];
            String cname = frame.getClassName();
            if (isPrintImplFrame(cname)) {
                break;
            }
            ix++;
        }

        while (ix < stack.length) {
            StackTraceElement frame = stack[ix];
            String cname = frame.getClassName();
            if (!isPrintImplFrame(cname)) {
                return frame;
            }
            ix++;
        }

        return new StackTraceElement(PackagePrintStream.class.getName(), "write",
                PackagePrintStream.class.getName(), -1);
    }
}
```

Then to install the stream do the following:

```
System.setOut(new PackagePrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only making minimal use of those classes you could do this:

There is a class you need to call that looks like this:

```
static class DontPrint {

    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Called from DontPrint.method()");
    }
}
```

During init create a logPrinter to use later.

```
 PrintStream logPrinter = new PrintStream(new File("dontprint.log"));
```

Then everytime you call its methods you could use setOut() to redirect.

```
System.out.println("first print from main");
PrintStream orig_out = System.out;

System.setOut(logPrinter);
new DontPrint().method();
System.setOut(orig_out);
System.out.println("second call from main");
```

Of course if you have to do this a lot it will be very inconvenient. You might create a wrapper class to keep swapping the output back and forth, or fix it in the library source if you can. Logging frameworks allow different output levels and different output files to be configured for different classes so that would be a more complete solution. Manually redirecting out is more of a temporary workaround.