# Java Custom Logger - Not logging proper classname

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I am trying to create a Custom Logger.
My code is given below and the Properties file is also given below.

It works in the sense that I get log messages and details in the log file in the format I want.
However, all logs are logged with same ClassName - MyLogger. I want the 'name' I am passing in the constructor to be logged as ClassName instead of the MyLogger ClassName.
Appreciate any help in that regard.

Java Code:

```
    public class MyLogger {

    private static Logger log;
    
    public static MyLogger getLogger(String name) {
        return new MyLogger(name);
    }

    private MyLogger(String name) {
        log = Logger.getLogger(name);
        try {
            LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(new FileInputStream("./logging.properties"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyLogger.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException | SecurityException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyLogger.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void log(Level LogLevel, String logMessage, Object param1) {
        log.log(LogLevel, logMessage, param1);
    }

    public void log(Level LogLevel, String logMessage, Throwable e) {
        log.log(LogLevel, logMessage, e);
    }

    public void log(Level LogLevel, String logMessage) {
        log.log(LogLevel, logMessage);
    }
}
```

logging.properties File content:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level     = ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = %1$tF %1$tT %4$s %2$s %5$s%6$s%n
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit     = 1048576
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count     = 5
java.util.logging.FileHandler.append    = true
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern   = ./logs/log-%u-%g.log
```

--

Comment: I don't understand.  You have a `MyLogger` but you show the properties for `FileHander`?  Do you have the part where you configure your logger? EDIT: also where do you *use* this class?

Comment: Why is the `log` field `static`? Every time you create a new instance that field will be overridden for all previous instances. Also, this `MyLogger` class seems redundant; unless there are other convenience methods you aren't showing here, you're basically just recreating the `Logger` API for no apparent benefit.

Comment: The Original Logger, does not load the logging properties file unless it is passed as -D option to JVM or the file is in Java Home. I implemented this class to Logger to load the config by default. That is the one of the benefits I am expecting from this custom logger.

Comment: try {
            LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(new FileInputStream("./logging.properties"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyLogger.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException | SecurityException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyLogger.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
This part is not part of the original logger and so does not create log files unless we pass it as JVM option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for [`SimpleFormatter.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format) explains that the source parameter (`%2$s` in the format string) is "a string representing the caller, if available; otherwise, the logger's name". This looks at the stack to determine the direct caller, which in your case will always be  the `MyLogger` class.

To use the logger name instead, use `%3$s` in the `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format` configuration rather than `%2$s`.

Comment: True but there's also an issue with the `static` as said in the comments

Answer (score 1):

Per API docs you can use the [log precise](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/Logger.html#logp(java.util.logging.Level,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) methods:

> There are a set of "logp" methods (for "log precise") that are like the "log" methods, but also take an explicit source class name and method name.

Combine that with the [inferCaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274271/how-to-selectively-redirect-system-out-to-files-according-to-the-packages/32276473#32276473) method to make your bridge look transparent:

```
 public void log(Level LogLevel, String logMessage) {
    StackTraceElement stack = inferCaller();
    log.logp(stack.getClassName(), stack.getMethodName(), LogLevel, logMessage);
 }

private boolean isPrintImplFrame(String cname) {
    return MyLogger.class.getName().equals(cname);
}

private StackTraceElement inferCaller() {
    StackTraceElement stack[] = (new Throwable()).getStackTrace();
    int ix = 0;
    while (ix < stack.length) {
        StackTraceElement frame = stack[ix];
        String cname = frame.getClassName();
        if (isPrintImplFrame(cname)) {
            break;
        }
        ix++;
    }

    while (ix < stack.length) {
        StackTraceElement frame = stack[ix];
        String cname = frame.getClassName();
        if (!isPrintImplFrame(cname)) {
            return frame;
        }
        ix++;
    }

    return new StackTraceElement(MyLogger.class.getName(), "log",
            MyLogger.class.getName(), -1);
}
```

Using this method your code will find the stack frame that is calling your bridge logger that is not the bridge logger itself.